# Why fn. isn't a fn. (prototypes)?

Tags: javascript

Console said

> Uncaught TypeError: Game.start is not a function.

JS:

```
window.onload = function () {

let socket = io();

function Game() {
    let self = this;
}

Game.prototype.start = function () {
    alert("something");
}

socket.on("ready", function (data) {
    Game.start();
    console.log("this console.log is work");
});
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You need to do `var game = new Game();` then you can do `game.start()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Game.prototype.start()
```

or

```
(new Game()).start();
```

Some explanations:
Game will look like this:

```
Game={
 prototype:{
   start:function(){}
 }
 }
```

So *Game.start()* wont work as theres no start in Game.
If you do *new Game* it creates an instance that *inherits* from Game.prototype. Therefore you can call *start* on that instance. If you wanna call some other functions on that game instance you might store it in a variable

```
mygameinstance = new Game;
mygameinstance.start();
mygameinstance.dosomeweirdstuff();
```

I think you havent had a deeper look into *inheritance* ...

Comment: Thanks for explanations!

Answer (score 0):

Keep scope by using => instead of function.

```
socket.on("ready", data => {
    Game.start();
    console.log("this console.log is work");
});
```

Comment: why would you prefer *this* being *window* instead of the *socket object* ? Also its not about *scope* but about *context*

Comment: In _this_ (terrible pun) case you'd want `this` to be the socket object more often than not, also this doesn't really fix the problem at hand.